# Is Javascript's setInterval killed when the parent object is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a global variable
`global.loggedInUsers = {};`. This object is used as and dictionary is occupied with unique `key:value` pairs.

The key is unique an the value is an account object.

```
function Account(hash, jsonData) {
  this.hash = hash;
  this.accountJson = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  this.pongUpdate = 20;
  setInterval(function() {
    // Stuff happens here blah blah
  }, 1000);
}

Account.protoype....
```

At some point in my code eventually I call the delete function

```
delete(loggedInUsers.key);
```

Because the `Account` class encases the `setInterval` call, if the `Account` object is deleted will the setInterval stop or do I have to store setInterval in a variable handle it in a destructor?

Comment: Make a test case and find out... Answer it keeps running...

Comment: I was going to comment like @epascarello because the event loop is pretty opaque. I just read both mozillas and node.js documentation and they didn't mention anything about how the setInterval is scheduled. unfortunately the easiest way is usually a test it out :( and observe it yourself

Comment: Thanks for your help @dm03514 the last thing I wanted to do was create a unit test because of how big the code is. The code works but I am trying to optimize it. I also read the documentation before posting the question and could not conclude. Well thank you guys ill build up a simple unit test class and find out myself.

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking, the answer to the title is yes ;-) Since setInterval is a method of window/global object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference to the function in `setInterval` exists, and since you didn't use the `clearInterval` - it will keep running.

```js
var t = 1;
function Account() {
  this.a = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('a ' + t)
    t += 1
  }, 1000);
}

a = new Account();
setTimeout(function() {
  delete(a)
}, 3000)
```

Note that in `javascript` there is not way to create a `Destructor` function, so once you `delete` the object you will need to make sure the `setInterval` is also cleared:

```js
var t = 1;
Account = function() {
  this.a = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('a ' + t)
    t += 1
  }, 1000);
}
Account.prototype.clear = function() {
  clearInterval(this.a)
}

a = new Account();

setTimeout(function() {
  a.clear()
  delete(a)
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me the unit testing time. Could I ask why setInterval isn't destroyed along with the class?

Comment: As long as you didn't call the `clearInterval` - there is no clear. The function has a reference (from the current `window/application`) scope, and it will keep running.

Comment: ahh its referenced from `window/application` that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Mozzie—setInterval has no idea of how it was called or where from, so it doesn't know that the object was destroyed.